# Converting non-trivial code to new .NET async pattern - how to handle yield loops

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-ctp

I am writing a library to work with Azure Table Storage. The basic pattern is that a given HTTP request returns a number results in the content stream, and a pointer to the next set of results in the headers. As the results are read from the stream, they are yielded. I am using the System.Net.Http library (previously Microsoft.Net.Http), which in the latest version removed the synchronous version of HttpClient.Send and other synchronous methods. The new version uses Tasks. I've used Tasks before, but not for something this complex, and I am having a hard time getting a start.

The calls that have been converted to the async pattern are: HttpClient.Send, response.Context.ContentReadSteam. I've cleaned up the code so that the important parts are shown.

```
var queryUri = _GetTableQueryUri(tableServiceUri, tableName, query, null, null, timeout);
while(true) {
    var continuationParitionKey = "";
    var continuationRowKey = "";
    using (var request = GetRequest(queryUri, null, action.Method, azureAccountName, azureAccountKey))
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = client.Send(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                continuationParitionKey = // stuff from headers
                continuationRowKey = // stuff from headers

                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(response.Content.ContentReadStream))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "entry" && reader.NamespaceURI == "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
                        {
                            yield return XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (continuationParitionKey == null && continuationRowKey == null)
        break;

    queryUri = _GetTableQueryUri(tableServiceUri, tableName, query, continuationParitionKey, continuationRowKey, timeout);
}
```

An example of one that I have successfully converted is below.

```
client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        using (var response = task.Result)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created && action == HttpMethod.Post)
            {
                return XElement.Load(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
            }
        }
    });
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to convert the loop/yield to the new pattern?

Thanks!
Erick

Comment: [The .Net 4.5 version of `HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) still has [synchrouns `Send()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159031%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Are you trying to build Metro-style app by any chance?

Comment: I am not, but for some reason I didn't see the synchrouns send (I got the new library from the asp.net project). I will take a look for other versions of the library. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've discovered, `async` doesn't work the greatest with `yield` right now. Even though they do similar code transformations, the goal is quite different.

There are two solutions: one is to provide a buffer and use a producer/consumer type of approach. `System.Tasks.Dataflow.dll` is useful for managing buffers in complex code.

The other solution is to write an "async enumerator." This is conceptually closer to what your code should be doing, but this solution is much more complex than the producer/consumer solution.

The "async enumerator" type is discussed a bit in [this video on Rx](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Rx-Update-Async-support-IAsyncEnumerable-and-more-with-Jeff-and-Wes), and you can download it from [an experimental Rx package](http://nuget.org/packages/Ix_Experimental-Async) (note that even though this is done by the Rx team, it actually does not use Rx).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to convert the loop\yield into some form of output queue, for example, like in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx) using a `BlockingCollection<T>`. So the caller of your method provides you with a queue to push results to.

Queue is convenient, because it decouples producer from consumers, but it is just one option. More generally, the caller provides you with a callback to be executed for every result you fetch. That callback should be asyncronous, it can start another task, for example.

Comment: I might take a look at this, but one of the reasons for the yield pattern is to avoid eating a bunch of memory in the library. It could be kept fairly low, if I add some code to handle the consumer not pulling items off fast enough.

Comment: @ErickT: The collection can be bounded in size and producer can check if new items can be pushed and wait otherwise. But I like the IAsyncEnumerable option above.